# bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: drivers

Laptop boots the live version and wireless works fine. I install full version, wireless does not work. Install bcmwl-kernel-souce; wireless works. An update or other change comes along, wireless quits. Is there a permanent fix? Why does it work fine on the live version, and not after an install?

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple attempts to fix, I decided to check settings in the BIOS. It turns out there was a setting related to Wireless that needed turning off. Wireless came back. It still is strange that all worked OK in the Live version without changing the BIOS. Oh, well, it now works.

Comment: What was the bios setting that needed to be turned off? I’m having a similar issue.